# How to replicate c++ printf function

Tags: c++

So i want to convert a string and variadic variables into a complete string, like how the printf function replaces the "%?"s with the variadic variable. Here is the function I want to create:

```
template<typename... Args>
const char * convert(std::string fmt,Args... arg)
{

  va_list args;
  int location = fmt.find("%d");

  /*Here is the code to convert the string*/

  const char* returnStr = fmt.c_str();
  return returnStr;
}
```

How can I achieve the functions/processes in "/**/"? Here are the problems i encountered:

to be specfic, my problems are: how can i delete a item from the Args... arg ? also, how do i return Args... arg to itself? do i meke a array or what will work?

Thanks a lot for your kind help!

Comment: We are not a code writing service. State a specific problem and we are glad to help. What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: would suggest searching for "%" and then working from there.

Comment: My problems are: how can i delete a item from the `Args... arg` ? also, how do i return `Args... arg` to itself? do i meke a array or what will work? Thanks!

Comment: As for "how to delete an argument" - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic  has an example  (it even has a simple_printf!); but do please remember that "delete" has a specific meaning in c++ and arguments are provided in a way that if you delete one, bad things will happen.

Comment: Construct a `std::tuple` from the parameter pack. Write a function that fetches out the appropriate part of a tuple, using an index computed at runtime. Not easy, since `std::get` requires a compile-time constant, but it's doable using a recursive helper class. These techniques are too complicated to explain in a few sentences on stackoverflow.com and require advanced knowledge of template metaprogramming. Obviously too hard for a beginner, so Instead of trying something this, keep reading your C++ book and continue learning templates, until the point you can answer your own question, here.

Comment: You are confusing two kinds of variadic functions, namely (a) variadic function templates and (b) C-style varargs functions. They are completely different beasts. Decide which kind you want.

Comment: what does the params of `va_start` do?

Comment: sorry if my question isnt clear enough, ill edit it. Just stop the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive templates and [std::string::replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename Arg>
void convertArgument(std::string &fmt, Arg arg) {
  int location = fmt.find("%d");

  fmt.replace(location, 2, arg);
}

template<>
void convertArgument(std::string &fmt, int arg) {
  int location = fmt.find("%d");

  fmt.replace(location, 2, std::to_string(arg));
}

template<typename Arg>
std::string convert(std::string fmt, Arg arg) {
  convertArgument(fmt, arg);
  return fmt;
}

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
std::string convert(std::string fmt, Arg arg, Args... args) {
  convertArgument(fmt, arg);

  return convert(fmt, args...);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << convert("%d - %d", "ABC", 123).c_str();
  return 0;
}
```

For each argument one conversion is called until all arguments are embedded into the string. You can specialize the `convertArgument` template for custom classes.

Add the end you can convert the string to a cstring.

Comment: i think you dont need the `void convertArgument(std::string &fmt, int arg)` part. Anyways, many thanks!!!

Comment: @EdenCheung The template `void convertArgument(std::string &fmt, int arg)` is used to reduce code duplication and to easily add specialized conversion templates.

Comment: I just saw... will `int vasprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, va_list ap);` work the same ? thanks!

Comment: @EdenCheung No, a variadic template is type safe. A variadic function is not.